# Reboot During Resume

Tags: 16.04, suspend, asus, resume

When my laptop resumes while on battery power it goes straight to the Asus boot screen and then reboots my system. Thereafter I have no issues. Also this problem doesnt happen on AC power.

I have an Asus UX305CA Zenbook.

Comment: syslog is "old school" 14.04. Type `journalctl` in 16.04 instead. I just learned this today and hopefully you'll be surprised as I was. You can press `Page Down`, `Page Up`, `Up Arrow` and `Down Arrow` all withing terminal. Fantastic really. It's like graduating from Pong on B&W TV from 1978 to Mass Effect 3 in 2013.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I do like the line coloring. Back to the topic at hand, have you any idea of how to fix or work around?

Comment: Nope. The first idea I had was to tell you about journalctl and the second was to add the Zenbook tag to your question. Unfortunately that has been banned so I added the Asus tag instead in case other users with similar issues can help you out.

Comment: Note to future readers: The references to syslog etc are because I found a kernel stack trace in syslog which turned out not to be part of the problem. I have removed them for clairity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by commenting out the disk related section of my pm-powersave hook which I have copied below. I am not sure which line is the culpret and I will investiagte the battery implications. I don't think commenting these lines will hurt my battery since I am running an SSD, but only time will tell.

Im guessing that one of these commands is either not playing nicely with my SSD or the fact that I use full drive encryption.

```
battery_power()
{
#  ##
#  ## DISK and FILESYSTEMS
#  ##
#
#  # Set the disks to aggressively save power.
#  # Some might find these settings too aggressive.  If so, change
#  # "-S 4" to something larger like -S 24 (two minutes) and -B 1 to -B 255.
#  # -S 4 => put in standby after 20 seconds idle
#  # -B 1 => highest degree of power savings
#  # -M => not supported by my drive
#  hdparm -B 1 -S 4 /dev/sda
#
#  # Change ext3/ext4 filesystem settings to reduce disk activity.
#  # noatime => disable updates to a file's access time when the file is read.
#  # commit=600 => Change the commit times to 10 minutes.
#  mount -o remount,noatime,commit=600 /
#
#  # Set laptop disk write mode
#  echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
#
#  # Set SATA to minimum power
#  echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy
#  echo min_power > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy
```